# Cursor should remain on the same line after the for loop ends in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

This is my code and the test case fails as the cursor goes to the next line at the end of the for loop.

```
def main():
    i1, j1 = map(int, input().split())
    matrix1 = []
    for i in range(i1):
        a = list(map(int, input().split()))
        matrix1.append(a) 
    matrix1 = map(list, zip(*matrix1))
    for k in matrix1:
        for i in k:
            print(i, end=' ')
        print()
main()
```

[image]

Comment: I can't figure out what you want fed as input to test this, but maybe try removing the empty print statement if you're looking to not advance the cursor at the end?

Comment: Removing the empty print statement prints the entire output on a single line, and the output needs to be printed as a matrix.

Comment: ultimately you need to avoid that last one printing. There are any number of ways to make that decision but if you want the cursor to stay after the 9 in this example, you'll need to avoid that last print statement.

Comment: Can you please explain one way to avoid the last print statement, I am unable to figure out the solution.